# Am I interpreting K-means results correctly?

Tags: python, k-means, pca

I have implemented k-means elbow plot to find the optimum K for my data (after doing PCA). I have gotten the elbow plot shown below. My question is: I think the optimum K is 3 in my case (this is where a sudden drop occurs/point of inflection)? But looking at my X_PCA_1 VS. X_PCA_2 plot, I think the data can be clustered into 2 clusters only? or am I mistaken?

Note: I am still a beginner.

[K-elbow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXtdi.png)

[image: X_PCA_1 VS. X_PCA_2]

Comment: The graph you made between X_PCA_1 and X_PCA_2, from my point of view is 2 clusters.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos thank you. If I want to add X_PCA_3 and end up with a 3D plot, how can I do that? I've provided my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to plot to see clearly the clusters, first you can use PCA with 3 components:

```
pca = PCA(3)
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(scaled_df)
```

Then, you can append each point to each dimension:

```
X = []
Y = []
Z = []
for i in X_pca:
    X.append(i[0])
    Y.append(i[1])
    Z.append(i[2])
```

From here you can choose a library to plot 3d graphs.

```
model = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
cluster_kmeans = model.fit_predict(scaled_df)
```

```
df_graph = pd.DataFrame({'X': X,
                         'Y': Y,
                         'Z': Z,
                         'labels': cluster_kmeans
                         })

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for s in df_graph.labels.unique():
    ax.scatter(df_graph.X[df_graph.labels==s],df_graph.Y[df_graph.labels==s],df_graph.Z[df_graph.labels==s],label=s)
    
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you but actually my problem is in plotting the 3D plot, I've done these steps. If you can provide anything on that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I update the answer. Have a look at this plot. Let me know of any errors.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to understand it. Meanwhile I get the following error:

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/mm/r4gnnwl948zclfyx12w803040000gn/T/ipykernel_89990/3545887370.py in <module>
     10                          'Y': Y,
     11                          'Z': Z,
---> 12                          'labels': cluster_kmeans
     13                          })
     14 

NameError: name 'cluster_kmeans' is not defined`

Comment: You have to run the kmeans model cell, you did not run it.

Comment: I am sorry but I did that.

Comment: `
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
 

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters= 3)
 

label = kmeans.fit_predict(x_pca)
 
print(label)`

Comment: Instead of the name label, please define it like cluster cluster_kmeans.

Comment: Please accept tha answer then as valid. Cheers!!!

Comment: Can you just add the centroids for each cluster please?

Comment: you can use something like: 
Kmean = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
Kmean.fit(X)
Kmean.cluster_centers_
And then plot those points in top of that.

Comment: you are assigning s in the centroids, but we already assign s in the loop.

Comment: I found the problem. I was using plt.scatter I SHOULD USE ax.scatter THANKS A BUNCH FOR YOUR KIND ASSISTANCE!

Comment: No worries Bratha. Have a good day!!!